# Undefined symbol LAPACKE when importing Rust lib .so into Python

Tags: python, rust, shared-libraries, rust-cargo, dylib

I'm trying to create a simple ML library in Rust using crates like `ndarray` and `ndarray-linalg` and exploit it later in Python via ctypes. In Cargo.toml, I set `crate-type = ["cdylib"]`. My projet is built and works just fine in Rust but when I tried to import the output .so file into Python, it generates an error `OSError: /home/Project/Lib/regression_simple/target/debug/libregression_simple.so: undefined symbol: LAPACKE_dgetri`

I installed all lapack and blas necessary packages and lapacke.h can be found in `/usr/include/lapacke.h`

I can't seem to find any similar issue online. When I compile the Rust lib, I did see all dependencies package for ndarray-linalg loaded so I have no idea where this problem comes from.

my Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
name = "regression_simple"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.13.0", features = ["blas"] }
ndarray-linalg = { version = "0.12.0", features = ["openblas"] }
ndarray-rand = "0.11.0"
openblas-src = {version = "0.7", features = ["system"]}
rand = "0.7.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on a project, and the solution was to instruct rustc to link to `lapacke`.

I added the following in a `build.rs` file.

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=lapacke");
}
```

Once I did this I no longer got the undefined symbol error.